# Is there any way where user can put the text and show in the cv2 rectangle?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, face-recognition

```
def eye1():
    while True: 
            reg, webcamFrame = capture.read() 
            grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(webcamFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayImage, 1.3, 5)
            for (x,y,w,h) in eyes: #eyes er jaigah te just faces hobe mind it
                    cv2.rectangle(webcamFrame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2) 
                    #font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                    #x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                    image = cv2.rectangle(webcamFrame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 1)
                    cv2.putText(webcamFrame, 'SHAFIN', (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (36,255,12), 2)
                    roi_gray = grayImage[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
                    roi_color = webcamFrame[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
            cv2.imshow('ITS YOU',webcamFrame) 
            k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
            if k == ord("q"):
                break
```

**I just want to take input text from the user and show it to the rectangle form**
*"SHAFIN" is currently seen in the rectangle form *

Comment: feel like learning tkinter? you haven't shown _any_ use of tkinter in your code. -- this problem needs some kind of concurrency. either threading (if you wanna read from the terminal), or a GUI event loop running everything.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I just want to know is there any way to replace the "SHAFIN" and I can take input from any user and put it again in OpenCV rectangle form. Tkinter code may be appreciated.

Comment: yes there is. no, you'll have to learn tkinter. you are *not* gonna be gifted a solution. on this site, you're expected to do your work. you make the first step. show some initiative.